# How to define which aspects should be weaved into my project and which shouldn't in AspectJ?

Tags: java, aspectj, aop

Let's say I have an abstract aspect that is going to be used as a mother aspect for other 5 aspects.

Generally, I'll want to only have one or two of those aspects weaved into my project. Other times I'll want to have them ALL weaved into my project, and other times I'll want no aspect weaved into my project.

What is the easiest way to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define aop.xml files and supply them to include the aspects you want to be woven in and supply those to the compiler using -xmlConfigured option.